# Math.Random to draw image

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I am trying to use Math.random to draw an image.

Though I know I haven't got it right.

I know I need a loop to go through the Math.random function, but don't know how to implement it. I also know I my spawnRock function isn't correct but do not know how to fix it. Any help?

This code also breaks my current drawImages.

```
        var num;

        function mathRock() {
            var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
            document.getElementById("num").innerHTML = x;
            }

        function spawnRock() {
        if (num = 2, 4, 8){ 
            context.drawImage(rock, 1500, 450);
            } else {
                }

        var rock = new Image();
        rock.src = "rock.png";
```

Comment: ‘if ( num = 2, 4, 8 )‘ means ‘if (num = 8)‘ (comma operator : (2,4,8) is (8) ) meaning ‘num=8; if (true)‘ ( = is assign vs == is a test) .

Answer (score 1):

**Here's a quick primer on `Math.random`**

`Math.random() * X` will generate a **random floating point number** between zero up to (but not including) X. So `Math.random*10` will generate, for example, 0.22, 1.56, 7.92 up to 9.9999999999.

If you need **random integers**, you can strip off the non-integer portion of the random number with `parseInt( Math.random()*10 )` which will generate 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9.

If you just want a **random "coin-flip"** (true or false) you can do that like this:

```
var randomTrueFalse=(Math.floor(Math.random()*2)==0);
```

If you need to **do something randomly 3 out of 10 times** then you can do that like this:

```
var thirtyPercentSuccess=( (Math.random()*10-7)>=0 );
```

Then use your desired version of the random number to choose whether to draw or do something else:

```
if (thirtyPercentSuccess){ 
    context.drawImage(rock, 1500, 450);
}else{
    // something else
}
```

Answer (score 0):

mathRock is working fine, but I guess you should assing `x` to `num` variable: `num = x` then in `spawnRock` change the `if` condition to `num == 2 || num == 4 || num==8` since `==` or `===` are used to compare and `=` to assign.